# Setting ruby path

Tags: ruby

I have installed ruby using brew and the path for the same is

> /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/bin

But, ruby -v tells

> ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

I set the new path in, ~/.bash_profile as

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/bin

Still, "ruby -v" is same as /usr/bin/ruby before the path i set when i tried echo $PATH.

Is there any other way to change the ruby path?

Comment: ... paths are searched in order.

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.5`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: You might have to `exec $SHELL` to restart the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try `which ruby` it will report the path of the `ruby` being used, it will probably be earlier in `PATH` than the `ruby` you want to use.

So swap them round:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/bin:$PATH
```

Then restart the shell with `exec $SHELL`.

You could also use something which manages the paths automatically based on a `.ruby-version` file such as [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). For installing rubies [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) is really nice.